# How to get Date property with nullabe DateTime object?

Tags: datetime, nullable

I have nullable DateTime object:

```
DateTime? returnTime;
```

But, I can't get its Date property. Actually, there's no any DateTime property available for that object.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer with assumption that you are using C#:
You are using [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so you can check if there is a value with `.HasValue` and get this value with `.Value`:

```
if (returnTime.HasValue)
    foo(returnTime.Value);
```